# Inverse of $ab$ and its order in a group with relations $a^2=e=b^6$ and $ab=b^4a$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, order-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group, with $a^2=e, b^6=e$ and $ab=b^4a.$ Find the order of $ab$ and express the inverse in each of the terms $a^mb^n$ and $b^ma^n.$

Just want to cross check my solution.
Would be very grateful for the complete solution.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: My order for $ab$ is coming out to be 12. And thats not the answer given in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $ab=b^4a$ we get $aba^{-1}=b^4$. Taking this at both sides to the power $4$ yields $ab^4a^{-1}=b^{16}=b^4=aba^{-1}$, hence $b^4=b$, that is $b^3=e$ and $b$ has order $3$. We now see that $aba^{-1}=b^4=b$, so $a$ and $b$ *commute*. The order of $ab$ is therefore the l.c.m. of $3$ and $2$, which is $6$. Finally, $\langle ab \rangle$ is isomorphic to $C_6$, the cyclic group of order $6$.

Comment: Thanks, observe that what I basically used is the fact that *conjugate* elements have the same order.

Comment: $b^3=e$ does not implies $b$ has order $3$: it might have order $1$.

Comment: Yes, true, but if $b$ is trivial then we need to find the order of $a$, being $1$ or $2$ from the stating of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$ab=b^4a\\
(ab)^2=b^4aab=b^5\\
(ab)^3=abb^5=ab^6=a$$
So, indeed $(ab)^6=e$ and $(ab)^3\ne e\ne (ab)^2$.

Hence, $o(ab)=6$.

$(ab)^{-1}=(ab)^5=ab^5=b^5a$, for instance